# TYPO3: How to handle missing typeNum?

Tags: error-handling, typo3

When given `typeNum` is not configured in TypoScript, TYPO3 will throw [Exception/CMS/1294587217](http://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1294587217).

Background: After moving from another system to TYPO3 we have lot of these exceptions as `type` param was used there as a form field, currently search engines still stores many links to the domain so users often meet the "Oooops, error occurred" page

I'd like to handle it myself i.e. by redirecting to 404 page instead displaying error (fide `pageNotFound_handling`), is there some ready to use solution or should I create this handler myself and interact all requests for `typeNum > 0` ?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I'm looking for `pageUnavailable_handling`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageUnavailable_handling']  = 'REDIRECT:/404.html';
```